# Converting cartesian coordinates to latitude/longitude

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, cartesian-coordinates

How can we convert Cartesian coordinates (x, y and z) into latitude and longitude (in decimals) in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15285-geodetic-toolbox

Comment: In case you are looking for a solution, this should be it. In case you want to implement it yourself, the first question should be: How to do this without matlab?

Comment: I tried using the geodetic tool box  [x,y,z]=ell2xyz(0.825478323219267,  -2.133569167552524, 6371000)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @H.Munster it seems like the [Geodetic Toolbox - File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15285-geodetic-toolbox) contains what you need.

In particular: xyz2ell - Cartesian (x,y,z) to ellipsoidal (lat,long,ht) coordinates

```
[lat,lon,h] = xyz2ell(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: Useful link, thanks! I was looking for conversion from lat/lon to UTM and this toolbox seems to do that

Comment: @DouglasG.Allen Please elaborate a bit, just posting this link means that everyone should click it before they can know why/whether they would want to.

Comment: There is a toolkit from NOAA that may be used in Windows. But it might have nothing to do with Matlab. It's just for general information in case anyone else wants to know what's going on in this question since it has been answered. http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/TOOLS/XYZ/xyz.html